# printf("%d %d\n",i++,i++) output

Tags: c++, c

Why does this code shows the output as "3 2" instead of "2 3" ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int i=2;// declare

    printf("%d %d\n",i++,i++);//print
    return 0;
}
```

Output is : "3 2"
Why it prints in reverse order

Comment: C++ why printf and it is undefined behaviour

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: Can I ask what prompted you to ask this question? If it wasn't a discussion about its strange behaviour, what was it?

Comment: @JosephMansfield: There's a daily "who will ask this question today?" lottery, and it was this guy's turn to be picked.

Comment: SO should add these questions to the list [_"What types of questions should I avoid asking ?"_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4):

In this statement, the expression
  "printf(...)" modifies the variable "i" more than once
  without an intervening sequence point.

> This behavior
>     is undefined.

The compiler has detect a case where
  the same variable has been modified more than once in
  an expression without a sequence point between the
  modifications.  Because what modification will occur
  last is not defined, this expression might produce
  different results on different platforms.

> Rewrite the expression so that each
>     variable is modified only once.

even you might get output "2 3" in different compiler

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation of `printf` is from right to left in here

First evaluate

```
printf("%d %d\n",i++,i++);
           ^
```

Then

```
printf("%d %d\n",i++,i++);
         ^
```

So you got the output as `3 2`

The behaviour will be definitely undefined due to the undefined evaluation order of parameters.

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.