# Value of a char ptr does not change after ++ increment

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, char

```
int main(){
   char* str="Hello";
     // str: 0x4006db, *str++: l, str: 0x4006db, *str++: e, str: 0x4006db, *str++: H
     printf("str: %p, *str++: %c, str: %p, *str++: %c, str: %p, *str++: %c\n", str, *str++, str, *str++, str, *str++);
}
```

I hope this is not another stupid question:

1. Why the value of the str pointer has not changed after I incremented it by `*str++`?
2. If the `str` pointer value hasn't changed, every time I do a `*str++` I should yield the same value, and not, `l` `e` `H`.
3. Why is the letter `l` appear first and not the `H`?

Btw, I also looked at the value of `&str`, it is the same before and after I did the `*str++`.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have undefined behavior.

Comment: In `str++` the ++ is a POST-increment. So it passes `*str` to printf and only then increments `str` (it will now point to the next character). And the parameters are evaluated right-to-left.

Comment: 'I hope this is not another stupid question' - well, unfortunately....

Comment: Please tell your prof/TA to STOP issuing such assignments, and to stay off the tequila when dreaming them up.

Comment: This is not a bad question but enough research for similar questions is clearly not done.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie how come the value of str has not changed after its 1st increment?

Comment: @CoolGuy care to elaborate which part?? Both deferencing a string pointer and incrementing a pointer seems legal to me. Note that I am not trying to modify the string at all, just simply reading it.

Comment: @MartinJames this is not a assignment or homework of any kind, just sth I stumbled upon while familiarising myself with the language.

Comment: @Chloe Using `++` without a sequence point in between. For the same reason why stuff like [`int i = 0; printf("%d %d\n", i++, i++);` is UB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21220630/3049655).

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked **undefined behaviour** by:

1. Modifying a string literal.
2. Printing a pointer without casting it to `(void *)`.
3. Modifying a same object multi-times between two sequence points.

Also note that the order of evaluation of the arguments to a function call is **unspecified**.

Invoking one undefined behaviour is fatal, which means everything from it working properly as you want to destroying the world can happen, and you invoked three :(

See also:

http://www.c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html

http://www.c-faq.com/expr/comma.html

Answer (score 1):

The C99 standard says in 6.5.2.2, 10:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and
>   subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

Indeed, looking at the assembler my VC2008 produced, the effect of the ++ was only visible *just before* the function call. During evaluation of the arguments, it used the original `str` and placed the ++ in a temporary variable. As the order of evaluation is unspecified, the compiler could also have used another strategy.

For example, as I have observed (and used) in older compilers, the arguments are evaluated right-to-left and pushed onto the stack right-to-left and all intermediate operations were visible in the arguments to the left.

However, as there is a sequence point before the function call, all the ++ operations were suddenly visible in `str` before the function call.

Nice example of Undefined Behavior (UB).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that if you study and compile / run it will help you understand what is going on.  Note when the value of pointer ptr_ucW0 is incremented.

```
/*
 *  36130330_main.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int main
    (
    unsigned int    argc,
    unsigned char   *arg[]
    )
{
    unsigned char   *str="Hello";
    unsigned char   *ptr_ucW0;

    printf("\n");
    printf("  Set ptr_ucW0 = str\n");
    ptr_ucW0 = str;
    printf("  Text            Address      Text                Value\n");
    printf("  str       :     %p     *str         :      %c\n", str, *str);
    printf("  str + 1   :     %p     *(str + 1)   :      %c\n", str + 1, *(str + 1));
    printf("  str + 2   :     %p     *(str + 2)   :      %c\n", str + 2, *(str + 2));
    printf("  str + 3   :     %p     *(str + 3)   :      %c\n", str + 3, *(str + 3));
    printf("  str + 4   :     %p     *(str + 4)   :      %c\n", str + 4, *(str + 4));
    printf("  str + 5   :     %p     *(str + 5)   :      %c\n", str + 5, *(str + 5));
    printf("  ptr_ucW0  :     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0++  :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0++);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0  :     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0++  :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0++);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0  :     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("\n");
    printf("  Reset ptr_ucW0 = str\n");
    ptr_ucW0 = str;
    printf("  Text            Address      Text                Value\n");
    printf("  ptr_ucW0  :     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0);
    printf("  ptr_ucW0++:     %p     *ptr_ucW0    :      %c\n", ptr_ucW0++, *ptr_ucW0);
}
```

Comment: One more thing, you really should not mess with the base address of the string, in this case str.  Doing so will only lead to bad things happening.